# Selector returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <tr id = "{{ x.id }}">
        <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.sth }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.sth_else }}</td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="edit_btn">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Executing script for edit button pressing")
    x = $(this).children().first().attr('id');
    console.log(x)
});
```

I'm trying to extract the id from the tr in the html, but whenever i get on the page and see the console output i get: undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: a `form` with a `tr` direct child? That's not a valid html and may be the cause of your troubles

Comment: A `tr` isn't a valid child of a form, so the browser fixes your HTML because it's ***totally*** invalid

Comment: Yes. You are correct! I changed the place for the <form> tag and everything is fine now. Btw. why is it invalid html?

Comment: because tr's are supposed to be descendants of tbody/thead/tfoot, which in turn are supposed to be descendants of table, they do not belong anywhere else